# How to access Field-settings in the widget formatter

Tags: 6, entities

I am writing a cck-widget/field and formatter. My field-settings contains a "base_url" setting. If I draw that out:

`http://example.com/ [_some/path/to/a/file.avi________]`

`http://example.com` is the base_url. `some/path/to/a/file.avi` is what user provides and gets stored in database.

The formatter should append that base_url to the user-supplied values:

```
function theme_video_url_formatter_embed($element) {
   return "$element['base_url']/$element['#item']['safe']";
}
```

How can I pass the variable from field-setting `$base_url` along, so it ends up in that formatter-theme-function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take number.module from the CCK package as an example; it allows prefix and suffix values in the field settings that are rendered in the formatter.

In `theme_number_formatter_generic()` the field settings are retrieved using this code.

```php
$field = content_fields($element['#field_name'], $element['#type_name']);`
```

The values are then taken from `$field`, sanitized, and added to the output.